# Build function in Step spring batch issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

i start working on a old project, when i imported with eclipse (maven) it works well, but with intellij gives that the build() function is not defined:

```
@Bean
public Step aggregatingStep(@Qualifier("aggregatingItemProcessor") ItemProcessor aggregatingItemProcessor, 
                            @Qualifier("aggregateDatabaseItemWriter") ItemStreamWriter writer,
                            AggregateDatabaseItemReader reader) {
    // set chunksize to 1 to force commit. however read in database is done with chunkSize property
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("aggregatingStep")
                             .chunk(1)
                             .reader(reader)
                             .writer(writer)
                             .processor(aggregatingItemProcessor)
                             .allowStartIfComplete(false)
                             .build();
}
```

I'm using springframwork batch v3.0.6

Any help ?

Comment: Are you sure your project is correctly imported in intellij? Intellij works well with maven projects so if it works in eclipse, it should work fine in intellij too.

Comment: Hello , welcome to SO , i think you are not referring the same version of spring libraries in intellij , please validate the version once